# Dragging content of overflow div scrolls in both Safari and Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I am trying to create custom ui using HTML canvas, but I want to preserve native scrolling behaviour. I came out with a hack, where I overlay my canvas with empty transparent div and repaint canvas depending on scroll position of the div. This works perfectly, except when trying to allow the user to *select* something painted in the canvas. Usually, you'd expect the element to scroll, which happens in both Safari and Firefox, but not so in Chrome.

Imagine following HTML code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.content {
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
background: rgb(34,193,195);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
}

.item {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will create two containers with scrollable content inside. Try to click and drag mouse button in both of them as if you were trying to select some invisible text inside. In Safari and Firefox, both containers will scroll. In Chrome, only the second one (containing inner `.item` divs) will scroll.

[image: Video of dragging in Chrome]

Is there a way to get desired behaviour in Chrome? I want to avoid creating huge (thousands) number of DOM elements.

Comment: I am using chrome 85.0.4183.102 and I am able to scroll through both containers with mouse scroll as well as click n drag.

Comment: @DipenShah thanks for the comment, I've added animated gif to better illustrate what I mean by scroll through drag. Does that really work for you in Chrome?

Comment: For me, in Chrome 85.0.4183.102, I can drag both. I have to hold down the mouse/trackpad slightly longer in the first box though.

Comment: It worked for me in both cases in chrome as long as my cursor stayed within the container element. But in firefox, I was able to scroll even when my cursor was out of the container element during drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for some reason Chrome expects some content to be in it for selection to work, unlike firefox.

You can mock the desired behaviour by having some text within your content div and setting its opacity to 0. Also use the CSS `user-select: all;` to select the whole text on the first click.

Note: The scroll only works when the cursor is within the bounds of the container (in chrome).

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%);
  user-select: all;
}

.content span{
  opacity: 0;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"><span>a</span></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do the trick. Sorry the bounty expired before I awarded it. No worry, I've started another one, that goes to you. Unfortunately, we have to wait 24 hours.